# Cumulative number of unique items in a table by group

Tags: python, pandas

How can I most easily find the cumulative number of unique items in column A for each item in column B.

```
    A   B
0   a   1
1   a   1
2   b   2
3   c   3
4   c   3
5   c   4
```

I.e. the end result should be

```
    A   nunique
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   4
```

(after counting unique values for 'a', we have 1, after counting unique values added by 'b' we have 2 and so on...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique().cumsum()

#A
#a    1
#b    2
#c    4
#Name: B, dtype: int64
```